# Manually editing maps

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have areas in my map that i woul like the turtlebot to avoid, áreas cold be marked as free or unknown, but for different reasons, such as carpets, cluttered areas etc i would like the turtlebot to avoid these areas in it's 'path-planning...

Is this possibe ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11641/manually-editing-maps./) by [hfor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1139/hfor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can edit maps using a standard image editor, so you can simply mark areas you don't wish the robot to go with black.  The image format is PGM

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the meantime somebody started to create an editor here: https://github.com/TheOnceAndFutureSmalltalker/ros_map_editor

---

Originally posted by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) with karma: 95 on 2020-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1